# Pre-fill user interface with ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I've played around with the Database Dictionary sample of the Google samples.

It does something like this:

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // handles a click on a search suggestion; launches activity to show word
        Intent wordIntent = new Intent(this, WordActivity.class);
        wordIntent.setData(intent.getData());
        startActivity(wordIntent);
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // handles a search query
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        showResults(query);
    }
```

I want to pre-fill the UI with data (the Google sample has an empty list). The query should be "*". How can I do this?

Comment: Can you post a link to the sample code you're using? What UI do you want filled?

Comment: yes it is this sample http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Database/SearchableDictionary.htm I want the search result filled with * on first start

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean by wanting the search result filled with "*". If you mean, you want it to show all the items in the dictionary, then you just need to call the `query` method with `query(null, null, null)` and that will return a cursor with all columns and all rows in the database. Is that what you want?

Comment: thats not the problem. i need to know where to put in the first query. there is this call, maybe i need to handle the prefill here:  private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent contactIntent = new Intent(this, ContactActivity.class);
        contactIntent.setData(intent.getData());
        startActivity(contactIntent);
        finish();
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        showResults(query);
    }

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i found it out i had to add this line of code

int count = cursor.getCount();
            String countString = getResources().getQuantityString(
                    R.plurals.search_results, count,
                    new Object[] { count, query });